# c++: Duda con manejo de excepciones

Tags: c++

Estoy aprendiendo c++ y quería probar un código utilizando try y catch. Asi que escribí un programa que deliberadamente enviaría un error out_of_range:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

class foo{
    public:
        foo(int s) :elem{new double[s]} {}//constructor de foo
        double& operator[](int i);
    private:
        double* elem;
};

double& foo::operator[](int i)
{
    try{
        std::cout << "se accedio a elem[" << i << "] satisfactoriamente\n";
        return elem[i];
    }
    catch(std::out_of_range){
        std::cout << "Ups " << i << " esta fuera del rango de elem\n";
        throw std::out_of_range{"Vector::operator[]"};
    }
}

void error() //Esta función esta creada para deliberadamente lanzar el error out_of_range
{
    foo boo(1);
    boo[1] = 1;
    boo[2] = 2;    
}

int main()
{
    error();
}
```

El problema es que incluso cuando intenta escribir un valor en boo[1] y boo[2] el output imprime

```
se accedio a elem[1] satisfactoriamente
```

y continua sin lanzar ningún error.

(Parece que cuando intento lanzar errores deliberadamente no consigo ninguno :P)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes una confusión. Una cosa son las excepciones del lenguaje, y otra las excepciones del sistema operativo.

Las excepciones del sistema operativo son lanzadas por este **fuera del control de tu programa**, y se manejan de forma distinta en cada plataforma, utilizando la API del propio sistema operativo; no hay forma, desde C++ *puro*, de controlarlas.

Una sencilla prueba:

```
#include <iostream>

int main( ) {
  int *j = nullptr;

  try {
    *j = 10;
    return 0;
  } catch( ... ) {
    std::cout << "Huy !!\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Las excepciones del lenguaje **han de ser lanzadas por tí**, y son completamente independientes del sistema operativo. Su uso es para facilitar la legibilidad:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

class foo{
  public:
    foo( int s ) :
      elem{ new double[s] },
      count{ s } {
    } // constructor de foo
    double& operator[]( int i );

  private:
    double* elem;
    int count;
};

double& foo::operator[]( int i ) {
  if( i > count ) throw std::out_of_range( "Te pasaste !!\n" );

  std::cout << "se accedio a elem[" << i << "] satisfactoriamente\n";
  return elem[i];
}

void error( ) {
  try {
    foo boo(1);
    boo[1] = 1;
    boo[2] = 2;    
  } catch( std::out_of_range &e ) {
    std::cout << "Huy !! ";
    std::cout << e.what( );
  }
}

int main( ) {
  error( );

  return 0;
}
```

En tu código original no ocurre ningún error porque la memoria que reservas no lo hace siempre del tamaño que pides. El S.O. reserva memoria en unos bloques de tamaño mínimo; tu puedes pedir 8 *bytes* y el sistema, internamente, puede reservar 32 *bytes*. Esto se hace así para facilitar la gestión interna de la memoria.

Ten presente también que acceder a posiciones de memoria aleatorias **no siempre provocará una excepción del S.O.**; pues ir a caer en memoria que hayas reservado tu mismo previamente. En estos casos, *corromperás* valores internos, pero **no siempre** se provocará una excepción del S.O.